# Do you say 'Tokyo has much rain'?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, polarity-items

> 1. It rains a lot in Tokyo.
> 2. We/They have much rain in Tokyo.
> 3. There is much rain in Tokyo.
> 4. Tokyo has much rain.

I don't think 4 is correct or at least I've never heard it. 
However, some teacher at school(not native) seems to teach 4 as well.. now I'm confused.

Comment: "It rains a lot in Tokyo." "Tokyo gets a lot of rain." are standard. You should stay with "a lot of". "much rain" sounds awkward, though informally "Tokyo doesn't get much rain." might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use *much* in questions and negatives.  So the sentences # 2-4 are not appropriate.  The sentence #1 is very common or idiomatic.  Alternatively, you can say:

> Tokyo gets a lot of rain.

or

> Tokyo has a lot of rain.

However, the usage of the verb *get* is more common than that of the verb *have*.

Answer (score 0):

> Tokyo gets a lot of rain.
>
> It rains a lot in Tokyo.

These are probably the most common.  There are many other variations, of course, but most will be similar to one of these two sentences.  For example:

> Tokyo experiences frequent rainstorms.
>
> Tokyo has a lot of rainy weather.
>
> It often rains in Tokyo.

and so on.